# Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist

Tags: windows, laravel

i followed these , laravel virsion 5.4.16
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqkt6eSsRZs&t=29s

Comment: Can you include the whole error message might be easier to answer

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ReflectionException in Container.php line 719: Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You need to regenerate namespaces autoload

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

"php artisan make:auth" produces all the authentication scaffolding required for the authentication process.

Type "php artisan make:auth" in your terminal right in the directory of your project. You will need to tidy up your install by deleting the "layouts folder" folder within the "resources folder", and also change the "@extends('layouts.app')" to "@extends('main')" in the login.blade.php and register.blade.php views within the "resources/views/auth" folder. Also you should then run "php artisan route:list" to see the names and locations of the auth routes.

I hope this helps